# Tipa throwing error because of `\implies` and `\iff`. Workaround or fix?

Tags: errors, compiling, tipa

I need to use the [Tipa](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipa?lang=en) package. Upon imorting it my document stopped compiling. After frantically dissecting it I figured out Tipa throws an error when `\implies` or `\iff` is present in the source text.

This is... weird to say the least. These are standard commands. Hence, this must be a known issue. Is there any workaround? Or do I have to replace every `\implies` with a `\Longrightarrow` and every `\iff` by an `\Longleftrightarrow` now in my entire document?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tipa}


\begin{document}

$\implies$
\end{document}
```

The error (compiled with pdfLaTex):

```
 name4.tex, line 8
Missing } inserted.

<inserted text> 
                }
l.8 $\implies$

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

 name4.tex, line 8
Too many }'s.

\UseTextAccent ...se@text@encoding \@curr@enc #3}}

l.8 $\implies$

You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tipa` package redefines some macros that can interfere with `amsmath`. The best solution is to load it with the `[safe]` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}

\begin{document}
$\implies$
\end{document}
```

For more explanation, and a list of the commands that the `[safe]` mode disables, see p. 12 of the [TIPA documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tipa).

[image: output of code]